# Powershell Remove part of Video filename containing Square/Round brackets and everything inside those brackets

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, replace, regex-replace

I have several videos that has either round brackets and/or square brackets with some text inside those like `(ANTYHING HERE)` OR `[ANTHING HERE]`:

For example:
`MOVIENAME 2024 LANG [SOMETEXTHERE] 1080P.mkv` or `MOVIENAME 2024 (SOMEOTHERTEXTHERE) LANG [SOMETEXTHERE] 1080P.mp4` or

And by using Powershell with Regex text replacing, I wanna rename it to `MOVIENAME 2024 LANG 1080P.mkv` or `MOVIENAME 2024 LANG 1080P.mp4` means I wanna remove any round and/or square brackets and anything inside those with also removing any extra spaces, meaning find & convert 2 or more spaces to just 1 space, possibly in single `-replace` pass or couple such passes at most.

I tried doing this just for square brackets, but it doesn't work:

```
$validExtensions = '.mkv', '.mp4'
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File |
    Where-Object Extension -In $validExtensions |
    Where-Object Length -GT 500mb |
    Rename-Item -NewName {($_.BaseName -replace '(.*)(\[.*\])(.*)', '$1$3')}.ToUpper() + $_.Extension
```

Can anyone help achieving what I want here ?

Comment: You need an array : $validExtensions = @('.mkv', '.mp4')

Comment: Actually even with the way `$validExtensions` are declared now, it does other replacements, but IDK why it doesn't do any regex replacements specifically involving any kind of brackets, also incl. square ones, on that I am lost, cause the syntax looks correct, unless I ain't aware of any nuances of Powershell with brackets in regex

Comment: @jdweng: `$validExtensions = '.mkv', '.mp4'` _is_ an array: you _may_ but _don't need to_ use `@(...)`to create an array - `,` constructs them on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain two `-replace` operations, as follows:

```bash
($_.BaseName -replace '[[(].*[])]' -replace '  +', ' ').ToUpper() + $_.Extension
```

- The first one removes any `[...]` and `(...)` tokens from the string .

  - Strictly speaking, it would also remove tokens with mismatched delimiters, e.g. `[...)`
  - If that is a concern, use the regex suggested by [TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician):
    `'\[.*?\]|\(.*?\)'`
- The second replaces runs of two or more spaces with a single space each.

Comment: for safety you could do `'\[.*?\]|\(.*?\)'` to avoid `[...)` type matches if that becomes problematic

Comment: Good point, @TheMadTechnician, thanks - I've added your suggestion to the answer.